# Diacritic Sensitive Search PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, diacritics

Hlo...

I've been making a spell checker of Punjabi. Everything is working fine except the diacritics of Punjabi Language. Like `e` and `é`, Punjabi too has diacritics which are `ਸ` and `ਸ਼`. But the problem is that when i search in the database, it considers the word with `ਸ਼` and `ਸ` the same. The database is stored with words in `utf-8` format. I am using collation `utf8_unicode_ci` for the database and the tables as well.

```
mysql_query("SET charset utf8");
$exists = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(word) FROM unicode WHERE word = '$str'");
```

If the count is 0, it says the word is wrong. `$str` is the word. When i try to search, it says the word with both `ਸ` and `ਸ਼` correct. The word with `ਸ਼` is correct.

I've tried to change the collation to `utf8_bin` with `COLLATE utf8_bin`, but it says both the words wrong `ਸ` and `ਸ਼`. I've even tried `utf8_general_ci` and changing the collation of the table and database.

It either says both incorrect, or both correct. But one of them is correct.

My main problem is diacritic sensitive search which doesn't work with `utf8_bin` either...

Plzz Help..Thxx in advance....

Comment: Your 'example' isn't working for me. Both the queries "select 'ਸ' like 'ਸ਼' COLLATE utf8_bin; # gives 0" and "select 'ਸ' like 'ਸ਼' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; # gives 0" appear to be correct. Can you give an actual example and the results that you see.

Comment: PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(word) FROM unicode WHERE BINARY word = '$str'
```

The `BINARY` keyword causes mysql to do a direct bit-by-bit comparison.

Comment: hey...i got to kno the problem....i noticed that with this..when the diacritic is at the end of the word, it works very well...but when it is in d beginning of the word or in the middle, it does not workk...thx